# Why joining two tables onto parent table returns empty query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I am new to postgres and this schema is a work in progress, there is a lot of redundant columns for data checks.

Why do I receive an empty query when I join "penn_survey" and "brazil_legacy_survey" onto the "visit" table? If I join only "penn_survey" onto the "visit" table the query works correctly and vice versa for "brazil_legacy_survey". Yet when I try join both survey tables back onto the "visit" table in a single query it returns an empty table.

Do I need different column headers or separate foreign key IDs? Is my understanding of the structure for join

```
-- Data Check
select v.date, v.site, ps.site, ps.date, b.site, b.date
from visit v 
join penn_survey ps on ps.visit_id = v.visit_id 
join brazil_legacy_survey b on b.visit_id = v.visit_id
```

[image]

[image]

```
-- Joining only penn_survey table
select v.date, v.site, ps.site, ps.date
from visit v 
join penn_survey ps on ps.visit_id = v.visit_id
```

[image]

Comment: So you have the same visit_id in all 3 tables? You may want to `left join` the two survey tables, or, UNION two queries.

Comment: @Isolated within the survey tables, the visit ID was populated when "site", "date", and "survey_time" equal each other between the visit table and survey table of interest. So the two survey tables both have a visit_id column populated off those three variables.

Comment: The answer depends on what the data in the tables mean and what you want to achieve with the query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe when I query the data I would like to have both the survey tables of interest to join onto the visit table based on the visit_id so I can verify the IDs have been populated correctly so I can then drop redundant columns

Comment: @Isolated ok so the left_join worked. I think it was just a misunderstanding of query

Comment: How would I adjust the query so I have just one site and date column from the two survey tables of interest? Would that involve the union approach?

Comment: I think `UNION` is a better approach. It will allow you to easily keep only the data you want. So like this: `select 'penn' as survey, x.date, x.site from (rest of query) ..... UNION select 'brazil', x.date, x.site (rest of query).....`

Comment: @Isolated one more question, what would be the query structure if I wanted to select date and site from the visit table, union the site and date columns from both survey tables, and join on the visit id? I want a total 4 columns with site from the  visit table, site from both survey tables, date from the visit table, and date from both survey tables?

Comment: Just modified the answer, which returns those 4 columns plus a column to indicate the source value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comments, using a left join to both surveys should work, however it would potentially return additional rows of data unless you add a `where` clause that would include and/or statements. Probably easier to just UNION two queries and control your conditions in each one.

```
select 'penn' as survey, v.date as visit_date, v.site as visit_site, 
  ps.date as survey_date, ps.site as survey_site
from visit v 
join penn_survey ps on ps.visit_id = v.visit_id 
union 
select 'brazil', v.date, v.site, b.date, b.site
from visit v 
join brazil_legacy_survey b on b.visit_id = v.visit_id ;
```

Comment: thank you so much for the explanations. I now understand how to proceed